# Loop through listtbox contain file path in C#

Tags: xml, winforms, c#-3.0

I have very small silly doubt for merging xml multiple documents in C# i am using File select dialog box to select multiple xml files and then show it in listbox full file path.

After this i want to merge these xml files into one xml files.

```
  try
            {
                XmlTextReader xmlread1 = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\xml_zip\\xxx-20140220000508_1.xml");
                XmlTextReader xmlread2 = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\xml_zip\\xxx-20140220000508_2.xml");

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xmlread1);
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                ds2.ReadXml(xmlread2);
                ds.Merge(ds2);
                ds.WriteXml("C:\\SamlpleMerge.xml");
```

The above code is sample code.Which works fine only the below code is loop through.

```
        try
        {

            while (listBoxfilelist.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                string filespath = listBoxfilelist.Items[0] as string;
                XmlTextReader xstread = new XmlTextReader(filespath);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xstread);
                ds.Merge(ds);

                ds.WriteXml("C\\Newtest.xml");
            }
```

Thanks for your time and feedback.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is or what problem you are having.  Can you clarify.

Comment: Sure John.. I have first code snippet for merging two xml files. Which works like charm.
But when i have more than two xml files in DIR and i want to loop through all the XML files in once specific DIR and then merge it how would i loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop the `ListBox` thusly:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
for (Int32 i = 0; i < listBoxfilelist.Items.Count; i++)
{
    String path = listBoxfilelist.Items[i].ToString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && File.Exists(path))
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
        dataSet.Merge(ds);
    }
}
dataSet.WriteXml("C:\\Newtest.xml");
```